# How do I create a dictionary with lists as values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

How can I get this output:

```
{'Test 1': ['100', '88', '45', '59', '73', '89'], 'Test 2': ['90', '99', '56', '61', '79', '97'], 'Test 3': ['80', '111', '67', '67', '83', '101']}
```

with this data

```
grades =  [
  ['Students', 'Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'],
  ['Tomas', '100', '90', '80'],
  ['Marcos', '88', '99', '111'],
  ['Flavia', '45', '56', '67'],
  ['Ramon', '59', '61', '67'],
  ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'],
  ['Federico', '89', '97', '101']
]
```

Comment: Pandas may be a library you want to look into

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first element (row) of `grades` contains all the keys you want to use. Every other row contains the values of the keys in every column. You can use `zip` with unpacking like so: `zip(grades[0], *grades[1:])` to obtain an iterator that gives a tuple containing the key as the first element, and the corresponding column from every other row in the remaining elements. Then, you can unpack this using `k, *v in zip(...)` to get the key in `k`, and a list of the values in the column in `v`.

Then, you can use a dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary out of the result of the `zip` operation. `k:v` is keys and values for the dictionary, for `k in grades[0]` so each iteration will give k one element from `grades[0]` , then `*v` is a full vertical column.

```
{k: v for k, *v in zip(grades[0], *grades[1:])}

# Result:
{'Students': ['Tomas', 'Marcos', 'Flavia', 'Ramon', 'Ursula', 'Federico'],
 'Test 1': ['100', '88', '45', '59', '73', '89'],
 'Test 2': ['90', '99', '56', '61', '79', '97'],
 'Test 3': ['80', '111', '67', '67', '83', '101']}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you explain what is happening here ?

Comment: `k:v` is keys and values for the dictionary, for `k in grades[0]` so each iteration will give `k` one element from `grades[0]` , then `*v` is a full vertical column.

Comment: @norok2 indeed , `dico.pop("Students",None)` my bad.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi explanation in the comment

Answer (score 1):

```
dictt ={}
for n,i in enumerate(grades[0][1:],start=1):
  dictt[i] = [x[n] for x in grades[1:]]

print(dictt)

>>> {'Test 1': ['100', '88', '45', '59', '73', '89'], 'Test 2': ['90', '99', '56', '61', '79', '97'], 'Test 3': ['80', '111', '67', '67', '83', '101']}
```

`start = 1` omits from adding the labels to the dictionary values